# How do I get the source code of imported .py file, whcih does not exist anymore, in jupyter notebok?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Question might seem confusing but let me explain.

I was working on a jupyter notebook. I had some of my functions and classes in .py files that I was using with importing them in the notebook. I accidentally deleted (rm) these .py files. However, they are still imported in jupyter notebook. Can I restore the code that exists in these .py files from jupyter notebook.

Details with example:

I had parser.py file.

I imported the class that I was going to use

`from parser import Parser`

I can still user `Parser` class, however, parser.py is gone. Hence, whenever I will stop this notebook. I will lose `Parser` forever...

Comment: If the byte compiled file is still present you may be able to reconstruct it, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56817475/3279716

Comment: Unfortunately this post did not help. I am still able to create new objects. So, notebook still knows what was happening in that class. Therefore, I believe there should be a way to get the source code of this class from jupyter notebook... but how...

Comment: You should look for a folder called `__pycache__` in there you might have a `parser.pyc`. You may be able to use a [python decompiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287253/is-it-possible-to-decompile-a-compiled-pyc-file-into-a-py-file)

Answer (score -1):

If you can continue to modify the notebook where you have parser imported, you can try:

```py
import inspect
print(inspect.getsource(parser))
```

This should print the contents of the module that was loaded when you originally imported `Parser` from `parser.py`. If that doesn't work, try replacing `parser` with `Parser`.

[Taken from this answer on StackOverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/777875/9328279)

Comment: It does so by *reading* `parser.py`, not reconstructing Python source code for the object `parser`.

Comment: Nevermind, @chepner is right - time to keep digging